# How to save test data to be consumed by a spring batch integration test

Tags: spring-batch, spring-transactions, spring-test

I am trying to use my JPA repositories in order **to save test data into h2 to be then used by a spring batch integration test**.

Here is my integration test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE, classes = Batch.class)
public class MessageDigestMailingStepIT extends AbstractBatchIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("messagesDigestMailingJob")
    private Job messagesDigestMailingJob;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(messagesDigestMailingJob);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void shouldSendMessageDigestAndUpdateNotificationSent() {
        UserAccount userAccount = DomainFactory.createUserAccount("me@example.com");
        userAccountRepository.save(userAccount);

        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("execution_date", new Date()).toJobParameters();
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("messagesDigestMailingStep", jobParameters);
        //Assertions
    }
}
```

Notice the `@Transactional` on the test method. Unfortunately Spring batch uses its own transactions and my use of `@Transactional` clashes with spring batch transactions.

Here is the error message I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).
```

Can someone please advise how to insert test data to be available for a spring batch integration test?

**edit**: For good measure, here is the definition of the `AbstractBatchIntegrationTest` class:

```
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@AutoConfigureJson
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(Profiles.TEST)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.bignibou.it.configuration", "com.bignibou.configuration"})
public abstract class AbstractBatchIntegrationTest {

}
```

**edit**: I have decided to rely only on the `@Sql` annotation as follows:

```
@Sql(scripts = "insert_message.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(scripts = "clean_database.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
@Test
public void shouldSendMessageDigestAndUpdateNotificationSent() {
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@Transactional` from the test so that the `UserAccount` gets immediately persisted to the database. Then use `@Sql` with `ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD` to execute a clean-up script (or *inlined* statement) to manually undo the changes performed during the test.

Comment: Hi Sam! Thanks. I have decided to rely only on the `@Sql` annotation because I don't even see the hibernate/sql insert statements in the logs when I use the repository and no `@Transactional`...